# Proof of total angle from two orthogonal angles.

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Angles on timber board]

The image shows a rectangular prism with a surface angle (30 degrees from the y-axis) and a dive angle (20 degrees).

According to the below patent [1], the total angle in space from the y axis, the vector
sum of the surface angle and dive angle, can be calculated by the following law of cosines formula:

cos(total angle)=cos(dive angle) x cos(surface angle)

How is this possible? Can someone help with a proof?

[1] US patent: P.C. Matthews, J.F. Soest, Method for determining localized fiber angle in a three dimensional fibrous material, patent number 4606645 (1986).

Comment: I have no idea what concept of "total angle" they could be referring to. The "surface" and "dive" angles shown don't share common vertex, and open in opposite directions. Without some idea of what they mean by "total angle", this cannot be answered.

Comment: By the way,  "law of cosines" refers to a specific formula relating the sides and angles of a triangle. It is *not* used indiscriminately to refer to any formula involving cosines (and the same is true for the "law of sines").

Comment: Thank you for your input @Paul Sinclair. I assume the total angle refers to the three dimensional orientation of the wood fibers relative to the longitudinal direction (y-axis) of the timber block. However, the formula still seems to be pulled from thin air, and not derived from the "law of cosines", as far as I can tell.